# How can I use torch Dataloader to get Picture having same class?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision, pytorch-dataloader

in my dataset, there are 6 classes and 23 pictures per class
I used `torchvision.dataset` to make `ImageFolder` and it work well.

```
dataset = vision_dataset.ImageFolder(root = DATA_ROOT,
                                     transform = vision_trans.Compose([
                                                    vision_trans.Resize(256),
                                                    vision_trans.CenterCrop(256),
                                                    vision_trans.ToTensor()
                                     ]))

dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = dataset, batch_size = SHOT_K,
                                         shuffle = False, num_workers = 2, )
```

but I want to get batch images with same class.

```
...
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
tensor([2, 2])
tensor([3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
...
```

This is what I wanted label(batch data's class) form
but actually DataLoader will work like that

```
...
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
tensor([2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
tensor([3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
...
```

how can I get batch data per label?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot conveniently do that with `ImageFolder`. You should create one dataset per class, and load your batches from the dataset you need.

More specifically, assuming your folder structure is the one required by [ImageFolder](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/datasets.html#imagefolder), you need to create one small dataset class :

```
class ImageSubFolder(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, label):
        # Path toward the label-sorted subfolders of your dataset
        # Assuming images are named smthg like /path/to/label/xxxx.npy
        self._path = root_dir + label+ "{:04d}"

    def __len__(self):
        return count_files_in_directory(self._path)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return (np.load(self._path.format(index), label)
```

This is just to show the logic of the class, you would still have a few features to implement I believe (you can follow [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html)). "The remaining features to implement are left as an exercise to the reader". Anyway with this class, you simply need to create 6 instance of it (one per class) :

```
loaders = {}
for label in ("dog", "cat", "plane", "tree", "mug", "car"):
    dataset = SubFolderDataset(DATA_ROOT, label)
    loaders[label] = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = dataset, batch_size = SHOT_K,shuffle = False, num_workers = 2, )
```

Now you have a dict that contains dataloaders which load only the samples of a given class.